# How do I export data points from topology checker into an attribute table?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, attribute-table, line, topology

I used topology checker in QGIS to find all dangles in my roads polyline shapefile. The topology checker returned about 528 dangling ends, also called errors. How do I save these points into an attribute table or create a new shapefile from them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot save the dangles ends resultant from the topology checker into a new point shapefile since the points do not have any x,y locations and there is no option to turn the dangles into point shapefile. Hoping that someone can develop such an option to save the output of topology checker into a vector file.